# Do I need to nest lists in this function that uses map2?

Tags: r, function, purrr

it may seem silly, or that the answer is in front of my nose, but I'm not sure how to make this function behave properly.

I want to write a function called `loop`, which takes a data frame `df`, group splits it, and then to each of these data frames, it runs some function called `test`.

On the other hand, `test` takes as its a dataset `df` and a row index `i` as its arguments and returns a list.

For the sake of exposition, assume this:

```
    test <- function(i, df){
   df$V2[1:i]
}
```

Afterward, `loop` does some other things that don't really matter for this question.

Here is what I've tried to do:

```
loop1 <- function(df){
  
  df1 <- df %>% 
         group_split(UF)

  x <- df1 %>% 
    map(~ .x %>%
          nrow() %>%
          seq())

  z <- map2(x, df1, ~ .x %>% map(~ .x %>% test(df = .y)))
  

  return(z)
}
```

If I were to run `test` for only one data frame `d`, I would do `map(1:nrow(df), ~ test(., df = d))`

Unfortunately, my function `loop1` is not working. How could I adjust it so that it runs `test`for each row of each dataset in `df1`?

Here is an example:

```
df <- data.frame(UF = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4),
             V2 = 1:8)
```

And what output I expect as a result:

```
  list(list(1, 1:2),
       list(3, 3:4),
       list(5),
       list(6, 6:7, 6:8)
  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line

```
z <- map2(x, df1, ~ .x %>% map(~ .x %>% test(df = .y)))
```

the scope/usage of `.x` is confusing. Use an anonymous function to clear the scope or check the below function with minimal change in your code.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

loop1 <- function(df){
  df1 <- df %>% group_split(UF)
  x <- df1 %>%   map(~ .x %>% nrow() %>% seq())
  z <- map2(x, df1, ~map(.x, test, df = .y))
  return(z)
}
loop1(df)
```

which returns :

```
#[[1]]
#[[1]][[1]]
#[1] 1

#[[1]][[2]]
#[1] 1 2


#[[2]]
#[[2]][[1]]
#[1] 3

#[[2]][[2]]
#[1] 3 4


#[[3]]
#[[3]][[1]]
#[1] 5


#[[4]]
#[[4]][[1]]
#[1] 6
#[[4]][[2]]
#[1] 6 7

#[[4]][[3]]
#[1] 6 7 8
```